# Multiple columns in one SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Can i insert multiple values from different columns in one?

i have:

```
ref | alt | couple_refalt
--------------------------
 A     C       AC ( i want)
 A     G       AG         Etc...
```

Is there a simple way?

I tried with:

```
INSERT INTO refalt(couple_refalt)
SELECT ref||alt
FROM refalt
WHERE ref='A';
```

Is it correct?

But it gives me the error:

```
null value in column violates not-null constraint
```

Postgres want a value for each colum, why can't i update or insert into specific column?

Comment: You're on the wrong track... Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble!

Comment: Ok Thanks i'll chage the way i want to store it, but the SQL is it correct?

Comment: To achieve what you want you may replace (ref,alt) by ref || alt. But jarlh is right - it is bad design.

Comment: The correct syntax is `insert into t1 (c1, c2, ...) select ca, cb, ... from t2 ...`

Comment: Seems correct  but here's a error: null value in column violates not-null constraint
Error row contains: (null, null, AG )

Comment: Remove the parentheses (for the selected columns).

Comment: I haven't my query is:
INSERT INTO refalt(couple_refalt)
SELECT ref||alt
  FROM refalt
  WHERE ref='A';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing comma separated value is not the SQLish way to store values.  What you seem to want is a computed column.  Postgres does not support that directly.  One method is to declare a view:

```
create view v_refault
    select r.*, ref || ',' || alt
    from refault;
```

Other possibilities are:

- Define a trigger to maintain the value.
- Concatenate the values at the application level.
- Use a function-based method to emulate a computed column.

Answer (score 0):

In order to insert two values into one column, you need to concatenate them. In postgresql the syntax is the following.

```
SELECT ref::text || ', ' || alt::text FROM refalt
```

If you want more details, here is the [string documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html)